# Is it possible to make a custom, realtime twitter widget?

Tags: twitter

I'm having a bit of trouble finding any resources about making a custom Twitter widget for a site.

Basically, I want to create a realtime twitter feed to implement within a site, that automatically updates every few seconds to show new tweets.

I know this used to be possible, but it seems like Twitter just wants me to use their default widget these days instead of my own solution.

Does anyone have any tips / links to good resources?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Twitter have stopped this from being possible so no, unfortunately!

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is available which can be  implemented in our website. You can try twitters streaming API. Its a technique of keeping a permanent connection between two endpoints; one at twitter side and other at our website. The technique is similar to a chat application where connected ports listen for any changes and update the changes in our side.

Please refer twitters streaming API